# Make text fall of a line

Tags: text-manipulation

As a joke in a songbook I'm editing I want to make a phrase "fall of the line", letter by letter. I do remember a long time ago to have seen something like this in WikiBooks but can't find it again.

I recognize there are different ways to do this and some alternatives would be nice to learn about.

Example of what I wan't to be done, however it should be much more incremental and not fall of one letter per line. But rather a couple of pixels per letter.

```
He
  l
   l
    oooo
```

The letters should "float of the line"

Comment: See `\raisebox` here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Just not to leave the question unanswered...</sup>

The page you're looking for is the Wikibook one about [LaTeX/Boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes).

The command you need is `\raisebox`.

Since you're writing a songbook, maybe you can add some music notes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\musicnotes}{\raisebox{-2pt}{\raisebox{4pt}{\textmusicalnote}%
    \textmusicalnote\hspace{2pt}%
    \raisebox{4pt}{\textmusicalnote}}}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{-22pt}{\musicnotes}\hspace{-24pt}
\raisebox{-2pt}{H}
\raisebox{-4pt}{e}
\raisebox{-6pt}{l}
\raisebox{-8pt}{l}
\raisebox{-10pt}{o}
\raisebox{-12pt}{o}
\raisebox{-14pt}{o}
\raisebox{-16pt}{o}
\raisebox{-18pt}{!}\hspace{-26pt}
\raisebox{2pt}{\musicnotes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, and good thinking :)